# link .js file to .html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an order form with validation and computational functionality.  In the folder there are two files; 1) index.html and 2) app.js.  Both the .html and .js file are in the same folder.  I cannot, for the life of me, successfully link the .js file to the .html file!  I have read through countless posts here, and the only piece of advice I found was to link the .html file to a jquery library (which I did).  I have also tested the .js file to see if it is linking properly by typing a test message at the top of the .js file.  The result; no linkage!  Here is the code:

For the .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Order Form</title>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form name="order" method="post" action="/submit">
    <h1>Order Form</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Details</legend>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="required">
            <div>Full Name</div>
            <input name="name" required autofocus>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="required">
            <div>Email Address</div>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
            <div>Postal Address</div>
            <input name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1">
            </label>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <input name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <input name="city" class="city" placeholder="Town/City">
            <input name="state" class="state" placeholder="State">
            <input name="zip" class="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
            <div>&nbsp</div>
            <select name="country">
            <option value="0">Country</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
            <div>Home Phone No.</div>
            <input type="tel" name="homephone">
            </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Cell Phone No.</div>
        <input type="tel" name="cellphone">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Skype Name</div>
        <input name="skype">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Twitter</div>
        <span class="twitter_prefix">@</span>
        <input name="twitter" class="twitter">
        </label>
    </li>
     </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login Details</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Password</div>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Confirm Password</div>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Order Details</legend>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP001
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP001">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Smartphone</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="399.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>399.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP002
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP002">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Tablet</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="499.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>499.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP003
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP003">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Netbook</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="299.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>299.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Order Total</td>
        <td>
        <output name="order_total" id="order_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Name on Card</div>
        <input name="card_name" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Credit Card No.</div>
        <input name="card_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}"
        maxlength="16" required title="13-16 digits, no spaces">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Expiry Date</div>
        <input type="month" name="card_expirty" maxlength="7"
        placeholder="yyyy-mm" required value="2015-06">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>CVV2 No.</div>
        <input name="card_cvv2" class="cvv" maxlength="3" pattern="[0-9]{3}"
        required title="exactly 3 digits">
        <span>(Three digit code at back of card)</span>
        </label>
    </li>
     </ul>
</fieldset>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
            <input type="submit" id="saveOrder" value="Save Order" formnovalidate formaction="/save">
        </div>
 </form>
```

For the .js file:

```
(function() {
    var init=function() {
    var orderForm=document.forms.order,
        saveBtn=document.getElementById('saveOrder'),
        saveBtnClicked=false;

    var saveForm=function() {
        if(!('formAction' in document.createElement('input'))) {
        var formAction=saveBtn.getAttribute('formaction');
        orderForm.setAttribute('action', formAction);
        }
        saveBtnClicked=true;
    };

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', saveForm, false);
};

var qtyFields=orderForm.quantity,
    totalFields=document.getElementsByClassName('item_total'),
    orderTotalField=document.getElementById('order_total');

var formatMoney=function(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var calculateTotals=function() {
    var 1=0,
        ln=qtyFields.length,
        itemQty=0,
        itemPrice=0.00,
        itemTotal=0.00,
        itemTotalMoney='$0.00',
        orderTotal=0.00,
        orderTotalMoney='$0.00';

    for(; i<ln; i++) {
       if(!!qtyFields[i].valueAsNumber) {
          itemQty=qtyFields[i].valueAsNumber || 0;
       } else {
           itemQty=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].value) || 0;
       }

       if(!!qtyFields[i].dataset) {
           itemPrice=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].dataset.price);
       } else {
           itemPrice=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].getAttribute('data-price'));
       }

       itemTotal=itemQty*itemPrice;
       itemTotalMoney='$'+formatMoney(itemTotal.toFixed(2));
       orderTotal+=itemTotal;
       orderTotalMoney='$'+formatMoney(orderTotal.toFixed(2));

       if(!!totalFields[i].value) {
           totalFields[i].value=itemTotalMoney;
           orderTotalField.value=orderTotalMoney;
       } else {
           totalFields[i].innerHTML=itemTotalMoney;
           orderTotalField.innerHTML=orderTotalMoney;
       }
    }
};

CalculateTotals();

var qtyListeners=function() {
    var i=0,
        ln=qtyFields.length;

    for(; i<ln; i++) {
        qtyFields[i].addEventListener('input', calculateTotals, false);
        qtyFields[i].addEventListener('keyup', calculateTotals, false);
    }
};

qtyListeners();

var doCustomValidity=function(field, msg) {
    if('setCustomValidity' in field) {
        field.setCustomValidity(msg);
    } else {
        field.validationMessage=msg;
    }
};

var validateForm=function() {
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.name, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.password, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.confirm_password, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.card_name, '');

    if(orderForm.name.value.length < 4) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.name, 'Full Name must be at least 4 characters long'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.password.value.length < 8) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.password,
            'Password must be at least 8 characters long'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.password.value !=orderForm.confirm_password.value) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.confirm_password,
            'Confirm Password must match Password'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.card_name.value.length < 4) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.card_name,
            'Name on Card must be at least 4 characters long'
        );
    }
};

orderForm.addEventListener('input', validateForm, false);
orderForm.addEventListener('keyup', validateForm, false);

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
})();
```

Any and all input/advise will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the updated (corrected) code:

index.html: (didn't change anything with this file; just took out the modernizr.js link and the .css link)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Order Form</title>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form name="order" method="post" action="/submit">
    <h1>Order Form</h1>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Details</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Full Name</div>
        <input name="name" required autofocus>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Email Address</div>
        <input type="email" name="email" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Postal Address</div>
        <input name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1">
        </label>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <input name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <input name="city" class="city" placeholder="Town/City">
        <input name="state" class="state" placeholder="State">
        <input name="zip" class="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
        <div>&nbsp</div>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="0">Country</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Home Phone No.</div>
        <input type="tel" name="homephone">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Cell Phone No.</div>
        <input type="tel" name="cellphone">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Skype Name</div>
        <input name="skype">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
        <div>Twitter</div>
        <span class="twitter_prefix">@</span>
        <input name="twitter" class="twitter">
        </label>
    </li>
     </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login Details</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Password</div>
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Confirm Password</div>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Order Details</legend>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP001
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP001">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Smartphone</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="399.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>399.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP002
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP002">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Tablet</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="499.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>499.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        COMP003
        <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="COMP003">
        </td>
        <td>The Ultimate Netbook</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" data-price="299.99" name="quantity" value="0"
        min="0" max="99" maxlength="2">
        </td>
        <td>299.99</td>
        <td>
        <output name="item_total" class="item_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Order Total</td>
        <td>
        <output name="order_total" id="order_total">$0.00</output>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Name on Card</div>
        <input name="card_name" required>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Credit Card No.</div>
        <input name="card_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}"
        maxlength="16" required title="13-16 digits, no spaces">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>Expiry Date</div>
        <input type="month" name="card_expirty" maxlength="7"
        placeholder="yyyy-mm" required value="2015-06">
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="required">
        <div>CVV2 No.</div>
        <input name="card_cvv2" class="cvv" maxlength="3" pattern="[0-9]{3}"
        required title="exactly 3 digits">
        <span>(Three digit code at back of card)</span>
        </label>
    </li>
     </ul>
</fieldset>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
            <input type="submit" id="saveOrder" value="Save Order" formnovalidate formaction="/save">
        </div>
 </form>
```

...and the app.js file:

```
(function() {
var init=function() {
var orderForm=document.forms.order,
    saveBtn=document.getElementById('saveOrder'),
    saveBtnClicked=false;

var saveForm=function() {
    if(!('formAction' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    var formAction=saveBtn.getAttribute('formAction');
    orderForm.setAttribute('action', formAction);
    }
    saveBtnClicked=true;
};

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', saveForm, false);

var qtyFields=orderForm.quantity,
    totalFields=document.getElementsByClassName('item_total'),
    orderTotalField=document.getElementById('order_total');

var formatMoney=function(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

var calculateTotals=function() {
    var i=0,
        ln=qtyFields.length,
        itemQty=0,
        itemPrice=0.00,
        itemTotal=0.00,
        itemTotalMoney='$0.00',
        orderTotal=0.00,
        orderTotalMoney='$0.00';

    for(; i<ln; i++) {
       if(!!qtyFields[i].valueAsNumber) {
          itemQty=qtyFields[i].valueAsNumber || 0;
       } else {
           itemQty=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].value) || 0;
       }

       if(!!qtyFields[i].dataset) {
           itemPrice=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].dataset.price);
       } else {
           itemPrice=parseFloat(qtyFields[i].getAttribute('data-price'));
       }

       itemTotal=itemQty*itemPrice;
       itemTotalMoney='$'+formatMoney(itemTotal.toFixed(2));
       orderTotal+=itemTotal;
       orderTotalMoney='$'+formatMoney(orderTotal.toFixed(2));

       if(!!totalFields[i].value) {
           totalFields[i].value=itemTotalMoney;
           orderTotalField.value=orderTotalMoney;
       } else {
           totalFields[i].innerHTML=itemTotalMoney;
           orderTotalField.innerHTML=orderTotalMoney;
       }
    }
};

CalculateTotals();

var qtyListeners=function() {
    var i=0,
        ln=qtyFields.length;

    for(; i<ln; i++) {
        qtyFields[i].addEventListener('input', calculateTotals, false);
        qtyFields[i].addEventListener('keyup', calculateTotals, false);
    }
};

qtyListeners();

var doCustomValidity=function(field, msg) {
    if('setCustomValidity' in field) {
        field.setCustomValidity(msg);
    } else {
        field.validationMessage=msg;
    }
};

var validateForm=function() {
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.name, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.password, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.confirm_password, '');
    doCustomValidity(orderForm.card_name, '');

    if(orderForm.name.value.length < 4) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.name, 'Full Name must be at least 4 characters long'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.password.value.length < 8) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.password,
            'Password must be at least 8 characters long'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.password.value !=orderForm.confirm_password.value) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.confirm_password,
            'Confirm Password must match Password'
        );
    }

    if(orderForm.card_name.value.length < 4) {
        doCustomValidity(
            orderForm.card_name,
            'Name on Card must be at least 4 characters long'
        );
    }
};

orderForm.addEventListener('input', validateForm, false);
orderForm.addEventListener('keyup', validateForm, false);

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
};
})();
```

There are no longer any errors that arise when I use chrome debugger**

As always, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Side note** I know the .html head shows a "modernizr.js" file link and a "style.css" link, but I have not yet created these files.  I have only two files; 1)index.html and 2)app.js and both are in the same folder.

Comment: Try opening developer tools in your browser, does it give you an error message?

Comment: your js file has some errors and might not work due to it `Line 24: Missing semicolon.`
`Line 27: Expected an identifier and instead saw '1'.`

Comment: Michael, thank you for your advise.  I opened up chrome and ran an inspection and, low and behold, there were errors :)  I have since fixed these errors, but I still cannot get the order form to run properly.

Comment: Adriano, thank you for the details.  I have addressed these issues; I will soon post an updated (corrected) copy of my code, hopefully we can figure out what the heck is going on.  Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: I'm seeing the updated code largely working. Is it just the CalculateTotals function that is now an issue?

Comment: Yes Mic, the updated form is largely working.  However, there are some functions which are not; mainly, password validation (an error message should come up if the passwords do not match and/or are below 8 char) and the Calculate Totals function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing an error message (script tag IS working): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number on line 27 of app.js

In this part:

```
var calculateTotals=function() {
    var 1=0,
        ln=qtyFields.length,
        itemQty=0,
        itemPrice=0.00,
        itemTotal=0.00,
        itemTotalMoney='$0.00',
        orderTotal=0.00,
        orderTotalMoney='$0.00';
```

This would be in reference to using the number "1" as a variable name in "var **1**=0,"

After solving that, the next issue was an "orderForm is not defined" error on line 18. Looks like a scope issue to me where the variable is defined within a method, and other methods are trying to access it but it's out of scope.

In general from what I can tell, it doesn't look like your issue is what you think it is, it looks like you need to debug your javascript.

Most modern web browsers have debugging tools built in for that. Here's a guide to using Chrome for that. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Mic, your advise is much appreciated and thank you for the link.  I have addressed all issues you have mentioned, and have addressed all issues Chrome debugger found, but have yet to get it to run properly :(  I'll post an updated (corrected) copy of the code soon; hopefully we can figure this thing out!